# how to find html lable id and select(dropdown) id in Jquery

Tags: jquery

here i can find text id , in the same way i want to find label id and select id

```
$('input[type="text"]').focus(function () {
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   $('#' + id).draggable({ cancel: true });
});
```

Comment: What's the relation between the focused input and the select ?

Comment: So what's the problem? Have a look at [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mouse enter for label focus event as focus event is not meant for label.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TDK5e/)**

```
$('label').mouseenter(function () {
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      $('#' + id).draggable({ cancel: true });
});
```

for select

```
$('select').focus(function () {
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      $('#' + id).draggable({ cancel: true });
});
```

Comment: Is there really a focus on labels ?

Comment: Change to mouseenter, is that okay?

Comment: @Adil , demo is working correctly.... i have tried this already.. but in my application its not working...

Comment: You need to find out more what is different in your application